# How to stop xcuitest from creating debug description attachments?

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, xcuitest

When I run XCUI tests, along with the screenshot image files, there are text files named like 'Debug description for `WebView`_1_9B32A2BB-A692-45D3-B86B-A3A68A59595E.txt'. Why are they getting created? How to stop them from being created?

Comment: I face the same problem and I don't have any answer for now. I've noticed these files are created when I use NSPredicate to find views. Is it the same case for you ?

Comment: Yes. It is with NSPredicate.

Comment: The best way I've found for now is to run a script after test execution to delete these files. I'm interested if you have a solution to directly avoid these files creation.

Comment: I am also deleting the files after test execution. No other solutions found so far.